# How do I run Django test using a CustomUser(AbstractUser) class instead of default AbstractUser for correct ForeignKey assignment during test?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-tests, django-custom-user, abstractuser

I have a CustomUser model in 'accounts' app that overrides Django's default auth.User:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_type = CharField(max_length=8, null=False, choices=[('customer', 'Customer'), ('owner', 'Owner')])
```

And another app 'ecommerce' with a model Product (abbreviated for brevity) with a ForeignKey to the CustomUser field above:

```
class Product(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    [...]
    seller = ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='products')
```

When I create the new Product, I'm using form_valid() function on the model to set the user based on the request that Django uses via CreateView. This works when I'm working in a browser, however does not when I am trying to validate my ProductCreateView through a test a script:

views.py

```
class ProductCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Product
   [...]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.seller = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

test.py

```
    def test_product_create_view(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('ecommerce_post_product'), {
                'name': 'newProduct', 'price': 2.99, 'category': 'newCategory',
                'quantity': 100, 'shipping': 'standard',
            }) # error happens here
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302) # test does not reach this line
```

When I run my tests, this test always throws an error stating, `ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7fbce54f0040>>": "Product.seller" must be a "CustomUser" instance."`

I have tried passing in the self.user that I defined in the 'setUp()' function of the TestCase with a line `self.client.user = self.user`, but it continues to throw the error.

How do I get my test to pass in a CustomUser instead of the AnonymousUser that it is using when running the script?

Comment: Can you show your `setUp`? The error you get is saying there is no logged in user yet.

Comment: def setUp(self):
        self.user = CustomUser.objects.create(
            username='testUser', 
            email='test@email.com', 
            password='secret'
            )
        Cart.objects.create(owner=self.user)
        self.product = Product.objects.create(
            name='testProduct',
            price=2.50,
            category='testCategory',
            quantity=10,
            shipping='standard',
            seller=self.user,
            on_sale=False,
            is_featured=False,
        )
[...]

Comment: [...]
self.user.cart.products.add(self.product, through_defaults={'product_quantity': 1})
        self.cart_product = CartProduct.objects.get(cart=self.user.cart, product=self.product)

Comment: I also tried with the line "self.client.user = self.user" in the setUp function and it still threw the error at me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `AnonymousUser` because there is no user logged in when you access the view.  In your `setUp()`, create the user making sure you hash the password properly. Then call `client.login` with the credentials:

```
def setUp(self): 
    self.user = CustomUser.objects.create(username='testUser', email='test@email.com', password='')
    self.user.set_password('secret')
    self.user.save()
    ...
    self.client = Client()
    self.client.login(username='testUser', password='secret')
```

You can read more about what's going on with these changes [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login)

Comment: Same error. For some reason, it's not looking at the CustomUser model, but instead the AnonymousUser model.

Comment: Am I correct that creating self.client is "self.client = Client()" after importing "from django.test import Client"?

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer with another required change for password. You need to properly set the password when you create the user by using `set_password` and then saving it again (to properly hash the password). Then call `client.login` as is. Also make sure that you use the correct username based on what `USERNAME_FIELD` is set in your `settings`.

Comment: Nice. That was it. `self.user.set_password('secret)` followed by a `self.user.save()` got the login to return `True` Now I need to sort out my response status_code values. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries! Please do accept this answer if it solved your problem.